# http to https redirection for SharePoint 2010 Intranet site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to to carryout http to https redirection on SharePoint 2010 intranet site. and one of the approach which I got from search is URL Re-write.

I am trying to automatically redirect  http request to https request for my sharepoint 2010 site.

I am using URL rewrite module to acheive this and below is the rule i have used :

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)" /><conditions>
```

I have unchecked the Require SSL option for this site. But still when i hit the Http url it is showing " error 504" and the page is not getting redirected. 
Please guide me if you have worked on this.

If any better approach other than URL Re-write is avaiable please suggest.

Regards,

Paddy

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very easy way of doing it.

Create anew site called "redirect - http://www.site-name.com"
Map it to port 80
and put a webconfig with the following info in it.  This will be the only file.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.site-name.com" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Easy and works like a champ

Answer (score 0):

Why not [Alternate Access Mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173%28v=office.12%29.aspx)? As far I know, that is the way.

Regards!